# why i need sll to add four zeros in $t1, i dont understand the need to multiply $s3 with 2 twice using sll

Tags: arrays, c, assembly, mips, sll

c code

```
while (save[i]==k)
i+=1;
```

put i in $s3, k in $s5 and address of k in $s6

mips code

```
loop: sll $t1, $s3, 2
      add $t1, $t1, $s6
      lw $t0, 0($t1)
      bne $t0, $s5, Exit
      addi $s3, $s3, 1
      j loop
Exit:
```

Comment: To answer this question we need to see the declarations of `i` and `save`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your `save` array/pointer must be of some 4-byte type (`int`s?). Therefore to load `save[i]` from memory, the index `i` needs to be translated to a byte offset within the array, and then added to the base address of that array. This is done by multiplying `i` by four:

```
sll $t1, $s3, 2
```

and then adding `save`:

```
add $t1, $t1, $s6
```

This doesn't look like an optimized build though. Usually the compiler can re-write this code to advance a temporary pointer in increments of four directly, thus avoiding two of the instructions in that loop.

Comment: Indeed, the loop in the question is really inefficient, and could have used `lw` / `add`(pointer increment) / `bne loop_top` on a fake MIPS without branch-delay slots to at least hide some load latency, and avoid the unconditional branch.

Comment: @PeterCordes I actually don't know MIPS instruction set, but that looked unoptimized even to my eye :)